# Is there any alternative for GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I get a fill rate of about 30fps in my application. I know that  GLES20.glClear() is used to clear the screen for every draw. If i comment it i get a fps of about 60fps. But the output is not as expected. I have a content to be redrawn for the whole screen in every frame. Is there any alternative where i can redraw the whole screen with out using the  GLES20.glClear(). Please let me know if there is any way to play around with  GLES20.glClear() to improve the performance?

Comment: AFAIK glClear() shouldn't cost you anything like 30fps. Are you absolutely certain about that observation? Are you using the depth buffer at all?

Comment: Most likely frame rate is dependent on screen refresh rate. If rendering is not fast enough to produce 60fps, it will update screen every other frame. This doesn't mean that clearing screen takes entire 16.6 ms.

Answer (score 2):

If you overwrite the entire color buffer with your geometry each frame you can get away with just clearing the depth buffer.

Should save you some memory bandwidth.